# Recalculate a jquery matched set?

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have the following contrived example:

```
var allListItems = $('li');
...
doSomeStuff();
...
allListItems.css({color: blue});
```

now by the time the last line runs allListItems might no longer hold all the list items. Some might have been added to the DOM. Is there some way to force allListItems to recalculate?

I know I can do `allListItems = $(allListItems.selector, allListItems.context)` but is there something built in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, just do it again.

FYI:  There is a convention that jQuery objects start with $:

var $allListItems = $('li');

Answer (score 1):

Just do it again whenever you need it to be refreshed.  It's just a javascript object.  If you want a fresh value in it, then create it again.

```
var allListItems = $('li');
...
doSomeStuff();
...
allListItems = $('li');    // refresh to make sure contains latest li tags
allListItems.css({color: blue});
```

If you really wanted a method to do that, I guess you could use:

```
$.fn.refresh = function() {
    return $(this.selector, this.context);
}
```

But, it would only work in some circumstances because `this.selector` is only valid sometimes.  For example, it doesn't represent an accurate state after you've used various modification methods like `add()`.

Comment: Yeah, a more realistic use-case is when you are in a function when the matched set was already passed in, but I suppose something like `allListItems = allListItems.selector && $(allListItems.selector, allListItems.context) || allListItems` will have to do

Comment: @GeorgeMauer - you could make an add-on refresh() method like I've added to my answer, but it will only work in some cases (which is probably why jQuery doesn't support it).